# Meteor Cordova Print plugin

Tags: meteor, cordova-plugins

I am developing a Point of sale (POS) for my store. And I am developing a Meteor app that will connect to the POS receipt printer. But as you know you cant simply use window.print().

I read but didnt understand the Meteor documentation about this, and I have several questions about it. (https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#using-plugins)

I have installed the katzer/cordova-plugin-printer (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer). And know here comes the questions.

1.-  Once installed, I create a file outside the server and client folder and insert a statement such as

```js
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
  console.log("Printed only in mobile Cordova apps");
}
```

and then do I simply add the following line?

```js
    if (Meteor.isCordova) {
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    // cordova.plugins.printer is now available
}, false);
    }
```

2.- If this is correct, Do I create a Meteor Method in the server or in Meteor.isCordova? to call the following example.

```js
var page = '<h1>Hello Document</h1>';

cordova.plugins.printer.print(page, 'Document.html');
```

3.- Should I use server side rendering to create the

```js
var page = '<h1>Hello Document</h1>';
```

part.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your points:

1. Meteor.startup is run when the device or browser is ready (it's equivalent to what you are doing).
2. Create a method in the client code -  Put the check in the button click method. Something like the code block at the end
3. Server side rendering won't apply as you are printing from the browser

> ```
> if (Meteor.isCordova) {
>         Meteor.call("myPrintMethod",other-info);
>     } else {
>         alert("Sorry, I can only print from the device"
>     }
> ```

Comment: thank you @mikkel `({
  'click #imprimir': function() {
    var id;
    id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    if (Meteor.isCordova) {
      return Meteor.startup(function() {
        var page;
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', (function() {}), false);
        page = '<h1>Hello Document</h1>';
        return cordova.plugins.printer.print(page, 'Document.html');
      });
    } else {
      return window.print();
    }
  }
});`